# Sharepoint 2007 Create Reports 

Tags: reporting-services, 2007

I'm really new to sharepoint and I'm using sharepoint 2007. 
I need to create reports from the document libraries and lists. But i don't know how to do it. 
In a forum I saw I have to use "Reporting services" for that.but it's not appear in my central administrator site. What can I do for this?
Any way are there any possibilities to create reports from other way??
Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Reporting Services (SSRS) is a feature of SQL Server.  There are web parts that allow you to run SSRS reports on SharePoint.  You may also run reports against the list, but it is not so straightforward.  Here is a link to more information on the topic:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/ReportFromSharePoint.aspx

One alternative may be to evaluate whether you can create views in SharePoint as a substitute for reports.  Views in SharePoint are fairly straightforward to set up.

Another alternative is to use Microsoft Access (2007 or 2010).  You can link the SharePoint lists as linked tables within Access.  This is great solution if you are already familiar with creating reports in Access.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply.
The problem is "Reporting services" section not appear in Central administrator site. How can I fix it? Any step by step process..

Comment: Check out this 5 post series on how to configure SSRS and SharePoint.  It has a good step by step: http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-12-SharePoint_and_SQL_Server_Reporting_Services_-_Installation_and_Setup.aspx